# mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306'

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm recieving following error message, while I'm running Flask web with Mysql server.

"""
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2472)
"""

What's exactly wrong, and what should I do to fix this?

Moreover, Flask web stops when it comes to this error. Isn't there way to just refresh, start again the page and keep going after facing error?

Answer (score 1):

append http:// at the start of the localhost, check if port 3306  is running on another service, u can use the netstat command if you are on windows